# utilSetResponseBody FiddlerCore doesn't do anything

Tags: c#, .net, fiddlercore

```
oSession.utilDecodeResponse();
            body = oSession.GetResponseBodyAsString();

            if (body.Contains("<body>"))
            {
                oSession.utilSetResponseBody(body.Replace("<body>", "<body><script src='a.js' type='text/javascript'/>"));
```

This is the exact code that runs inside my

```
private void FiddlerApplication_BeforeResponse(Session oSession)
    {
```

event.
I can reach it with the debugger and everthing goes fine but in Internet Explorer when I select "View Source" nothing is changed.
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Please take a look at this link
[Fiddler's Streaming Mode](https://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/streaming.asp)

So you need to add

```
FiddlerApplication.BeforeRequest += delegate(Fiddler.Session oSession)
{
    oSession.bBufferResponse = true;                
};
```

Also please try to use

```
FiddlerApplication.BeforeResponse += delegate(Fiddler.Session oSession)
{
    oSession.utilDecodeResponse();
    String oBody = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(oSession.responseBodyBytes);
    oBody = oBody.Replace("<body>", "<body><script src='a.js' type='text/javascript'/>");
    oSession.utilSetResponseBody(oBody);
};
```

The problem is `body = oSession.GetResponseBodyAsString();` returns an empty string for me.
Hope this helps.

Comment: This only partially works for me. When the string in question is replaced in the browser I don't get to see the actual webpage anymore I just see a white screen. If I view it's source I see the full html and the replacement definitely succeeded. Is there anyway to also see the webpage?

Comment: This answer is half right. You're correct that to see the response, setting bBufferResponse is required. However, blindly using UTF8 to get the response body is definitely NOT the right way to go; instead use the GetResponseBodyAsString method to get the response body as a string in the proper character set (which may not be UTF8)!

Comment: @vasiliy-alchakov If this works, I'll love you forever.